# Test laravel Cache failed

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, caching, phpunit

I am trying to test via phpunit laravel cache (file driver). My test body:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Closure;

class CacheTestTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testCache()
    {
        Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
            ->once()
            ->with(md5(1), 120, Closure::class)
            ->andReturn('Closure');
    }
}
```

When I am running test, I get error:

> Method remember('c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b', 120, 'Closure')
> from Mockery_0_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager should be called  exactly
> 1 times but called 0 times.

What am I doing wrong? Where to get docs about *shouldReceive* and what I must put to the *andReturn* ?

Thanks for replies!

---

EDIT:

The code creates Carbon object and then check if it exist.

```
public function testCache()
{
    $key = md5(1);
    $duration = 120;

    $object = Cache::remember( $key, $duration, function () {
        return Carbon::today();
    });

    Cache::shouldReceive('get')
        ->with($key, $duration, \Closure::class)
        ->andReturn($object);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are testing, because your test is just a Mock and is not calling anything, so please, do share the full test and the real code being tested too. To know more about `shouldReceive` and that stuff, read [Mockery's documentation](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html) (that is being used under the hood).

Comment: I am trying to create cache and check if it was saved to cache dir. I have copyied this code from laravel docs and thought it check is Cache can be saved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code creates Carbon object and then check if it exist.

```
public function testCache()
{
    $key = md5(1);
    $duration = 120;

    $object = Cache::remember( $key, $duration, function () {
        return Carbon::today();
    });

    Cache::shouldReceive('get')
        ->with($key, $duration, \Closure::class)
        ->andReturn($object);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase this is not an explanation, is the user trying to edit the question and add more info

Comment: The code creating object $object with Carbon date, then Laravel trying to cache it with Cache::remember. Then we mock the call to the Cache facade by using the shouldReceive method, which will return an instance of a Mockery mock.

Answer (score 0):

So, I can give some tips based on the test you added to your question:

1. You are trying to test if `Cache` works
2. You want to check if calling `Cache` with the right parameters works

So:

1. Your test makes no sense at all, because you are testing if `Cache` works, and it does! It is shipped by the framework itself, so of course it is working. If you want to test a specific caching part of your code, that is fine, but just calling `Cache` and then checking if it cached, that test adds no value at all
2. Instead of having `Cache::shouldReceive(...)->...` after the `Cache::remember` (the part you want to test), you have to move that BEFORE you call it, because you are literally caching the value on your test environment, but then you are saying "if something calls `Cache->get` with `$key`, `$duration` and `\Closure::class`, then return `$object`.

To have `2.` fixed, you have to use this code (instead of using a [Mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html), use a [Spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/spies.html), this is [what Laravel says about Spies](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#facade-spies)):

```php
use WithFaker;

public function testCache()
{
    $key = $this->faker->uuid();
    $duration = $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 120);

    $spy = Cache::spy();

    Cache::remember(
        $key,
        $duration,
        function () {
            return today();
        }
    );

    $spy->shouldHaveReceived('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with($key, $duration, \Mockery::type('callable'));
}
```

---

You can read more about the [difference between a Mock and a Spy](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#mocks-vs-spies), but the long story short is that a Mock will *mock* what it will return when a certain method of a certain class with more conditions (or not) is met what to return or do, but a Spy will *spy* (assert) if those conditions were met AFTER you run your code.

Comment: This test was created after I have problems with cache. Somehow the folder permissions was changed and this how I test is it works (for future test).

Comment: @Denny okay, my answer still helps you but it is only checking you called it, it is not checking if the data is saved, and it will also not help, because depends on the driver you are using, if you are using Redis, every time it will work unless (of course) you entered a wrong environment, so depends on the driver you are using...